# Starting an App takes very long when using a custom shortcut in gnome wayland

Tags: gnome, wayland, gnome-keyring

I am using gnome 42.4 wayland.

I want to open the terminal app when I press Super + T.
In the settings under keyboard I set a custom shortcut:

- Name: run terminal
- Command: xfce4-terminal
- Shortcut: Super + T

Current behavior:
Pressing Super + T opens the terminal but with a 25 seconds delay.

Expected behavior:
Pressing Super + T opens the terminal under 1 second as it does when using  other ways for example Application launcher or launched from a terminal.

Additional information:
The problem happens also with Firefox so I think the problem happens with every application.
Logs when I use the shortcut Super + T:

```
Aug 15 09:52:20 laptop gnome-shell[884]: Ignored exception from dbus method: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.system76.Scheduler was not provided by any .service files  
Aug 15 09:52:23 laptop gnome-keyring-daemon[828]: The Secret Service was already initialized  
Aug 15 09:52:23 laptop gnome-keyring-daemon[10708]: discover_other_daemon: 1  
Aug 15 09:52:23 laptop gnome-keyring-d[828]: The Secret Service was already initialized  
Aug 15 09:52:45 laptop gnome-shell[884]: Ignored exception from dbus method: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.system76.Scheduler was not provided by any .service files  
Aug 15 09:52:48 laptop gsd-media-keys[1109]: Failed to call GetEnvironment on keyring daemon: Timeout was reached  
Aug 15 09:52:49 laptop gnome-shell[884]: Ignored exception from dbus method: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.system76.Scheduler was not provided by any .service files  
Aug 15 09:53:10 laptop gnome-shell[884]: Ignored exception from dbus method: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.system76.Scheduler was not provided by any .service files  
Aug 15 09:53:13 laptop gnome-shell[884]: Ignored exception from dbus method: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.system76.Scheduler was not provided by any .service files  
Aug 15 09:53:15 laptop gnome-shell[884]: Ignored exception from dbus method: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.system76.Scheduler was not provided by any .service files  
Aug 15 09:54:00 laptop gnome-shell[884]: Ignored exception from dbus method: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.system76.Scheduler was not provided by any .service files  
Aug 15 09:54:51 laptop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[884]: libinput error: event7  - SONiX USB DEVICE: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 49ms, your system is too slow  
Aug 15 10:05:38 laptop gnome-shell[884]: Ignored exception from dbus method: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.system76.Scheduler was not provided by any .service files  
Aug 15 10:05:38 laptop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[884]: Window manager warning: Ping serial 3433362 was reused for window 0x1a0003e, previous use was for window W51.
```

I think the problem is:

> Aug 15 09:52:48 laptop gsd-media-keys[1109]: Failed to call
> GetEnvironment on keyring daemon: Timeout was reached

But I do not know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue. The gnome-keyring was definitly broken, because other applications, that depend on it, failed as well.

For me, are reboot solved the problem. I guess, a restart of the gnome-keyring daemon might suffice as well.